# What do all the orientation constants of the ExifInterface class in Android mean?

Tags: android, orientation, jpeg, exif

I understand what the 
`ORIENTATION_NORMAL`, 
`ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180`, 
`ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270`, 
`ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90` and 
`ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED`.

However i do not understand what 
`ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL`, 
`ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL`, 
`ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE` and 
`ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE` means in the [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) class in Android. I have searched through Google and could not find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @downvoter Can you please explain the reason of your downvote? Maybe i can correct my question that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are comments from source code (*android\media\ExifInterface.java*):

```
// left right reversed mirror
public static final int ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL = 2;
// upside down mirror
public static final int ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL = 4;
// flipped about top-left <--> bottom-right axis
public static final int ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE = 5;
// flipped about top-right <--> bottom-left axis
public static final int ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE = 7;
```

I think they are self-explaining.